# How to filter data of object according to keys and make new array in react?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am working with the object like this:-

```
{
 0: 
  buyAmount: 16.664328043964396
  buyAmountInUsd: 16.685266204095775
  date: {date: '2021-12-07'}
  sellAmount: {USD: 500, INR: 35000}
 1:
  buyAmount: 1004.7015442959262
  buyAmountInUsd: 1005.9639175379324
  date: {date: '2021-12-07'}
  sellAmount: {USD: 1000, INR: 79000}
......
```

and I am trying to make a new array using `useState` hook with this data but the problem I am facing is how to filter data and make an almost similar array with the same data.

e.g.:-

```
 0: [amount: 500, date: '2021-12-07'], 
 1: [amount: 1000, date: '2021-12-07']
```

The problem I am facing is I don't know the approach how to get the data like `amount = sellAmount.USD` and `date = date.date`

I thought of trying the [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) But I don't think it will be a good hit.

Comment: That's not a valid object

Comment: Why do you have an object instead of an array? Take an array instad of an object, if you need an easy iterable data structure. This gives a control over the iteration order, too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const arr = [{
  buyAmount: 16.664328043964396,
  buyAmountInUsd: 16.685266204095775,
  date: {date: '2021-12-07'},
  sellAmount: {USD: 500, INR: 35000}
},{
  buyAmount: 1004.7015442959262,
  buyAmountInUsd: 1005.9639175379324,
  date: {date: '2021-12-07'},
  sellAmount: {USD: 1000, INR: 79000}
}]

console.log(
  arr.map(initialValue => {
    return {
      amount: initialValue.sellAmount.USD,
      date: initialValue.date.date
    }
  })
)
```

Comment: can I also add a condition in that like if USD is 0 then put INR

Comment: yeah totally, the argument of map is a function, so you can do anything you want in it

Answer (score 1):

The better idea would be the having an array of objects rather than array of array elements

```
let result = yourArray.map(each => ({ amount: each.sellAmount.USD, date: each.date.date }))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to ReactJS - just native Javascript object handling.

If your original data has the shape of an Object you can convert it into an Array like so:

```
const objData = { 0: {...}, 1: {...} };
const arrData = Object.entries(objData); // [[0, {...}], [1, {...}]];
```

From there, you can filter/map/sort your array with native array methods:

```
const reshapedArray = arrData.map(([key, value]) => {
  return {
    amount: value.sellAmount.USD,
    date: value.date.date,
  };
});
```

Then sort:

```
const sortedArray = reshapedArray.sort((prev, next) => {
  return prev.amount - next.amount; // sort by amount ascending
});
```

You can of could chain these array functions and shorten the syntax a bit:

```js
Object.entries(objData)
  .map(([_, { sellAmount, date: { date } }]) => ({ amount: sellAmount.USD, date }))
  .sort((a, b) => a.amount - b.amount);
```